# Some OpenCV functions having poor performances in my build (e.g. cv::threshold or cv::cvtColor)

Tags: c++, performance, opencv, build

I am observing very high execution times on some OpenCV functions in my build. For instance, simple calls to `cvtColor` or `threshold` like this ones

```
cvtColor(_frame_rgb, _frame, COLOR_RGB2GRAY);

threshold(_frame, _frame, some_constant, 255, THRESH_BINARY);
```

take around 20 ms to run on my machine (for a 1280x800 Mat). While looking into the problem, I tried simple reimplementations of both functions, and the execution is ~10x faster:

```
void _my_rgb2grey(const Mat& src, Mat& dst) 
{
    uint8_t r = 0, g = 0, b = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < dst.rows * dst.cols; i++) {
        dst.data[i] = (uint8_t)((src.data[i] + src.data[2 * i] + src.data[3 * i]) / 3.0);
    }
}

void _my_threshold(const Mat& src, Mat& dst, uint8_t tvalue)
{
    uint8_t val = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < src.rows * src.cols; i++) {
        val = src.data[i];
        dst.data[i] = (val > tvalue) ? 255 : 0;
    }
}
```

even though `cv::threshold` (`modules/imgproc/src/thresh.cpp`) is using a `parallel_for_`; and as far as cvtColor is concerned, I don't really understand its implementation (e.g. `cvtColorBGR2Gray` in `modules/imgproc/src/color_rgb.dispatch.cpp`).

I would think functions like these are heavily optimized, so I am sure there is a problem with my build configuration:

```
$ cmake \
    -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release \
    -DOPENCV_EXTRA_MODULES_PATH=~/opencv_contrib/modules \
    -DBUILD_DOCS=ON \
    -DBUILD_EXAMPLES=ON \
    -DBUILD_JAVA=OFF \
    -DWITH_CUDA=ON \
    -DCUDA_ARCH_BIN="7.5" \
    -DWITH_NVCUVID=ON \
    -DWITH_FFMPEG=ON \
    -DBUILD_opencv_cudacodec=ON \
    -DCUDA_TOOLKIT_ROOT_DIR=/usr/local/cuda \
    -DOPENCV_TEST_DATA_PATH=~/opencv_extra/testdata
```

Of course I forgot to pass -O3 to the compiler, but I was also wondering if something like ENABLE_LTO=ON would also affect execution times, or only the library size (as I gather from https://github.com/opencv/opencv/wiki/Compact-build-advice); also, maybe there are other build options I am not aware of?

Any help is much appreciated.

**Machine specs**

```
$ lscpu
Architecture:        x86_64
CPU op-mode(s):      32-bit, 64-bit
Byte Order:          Little Endian
Address sizes:       46 bits physical, 48 bits virtual
CPU(s):              64
On-line CPU(s) list: 0-63
Thread(s) per core:  2
Core(s) per socket:  16
Socket(s):           2
NUMA node(s):        2
Vendor ID:           GenuineIntel
CPU family:          6
Model:               85
Model name:          Intel(R) Xeon(R) Gold 5218 CPU @ 2.30GHz
Stepping:            7
CPU MHz:             2300.000
CPU max MHz:         3900,0000
CPU min MHz:         1000,0000
BogoMIPS:            4600.00
Virtualization:      VT-x
L1d cache:           32K
L1i cache:           32K
L2 cache:            1024K
L3 cache:            22528K
NUMA node0 CPU(s):   0-15,32-47
NUMA node1 CPU(s):   16-31,48-63
Flags:               fpu vme de pse tsc msr pae mce cx8 apic sep mtrr pge mca cmov pat pse36 clflush dts acpi mmx fxsr sse sse2 ss ht tm pbe syscall nx pdpe1gb rdtscp lm constant_tsc art arch_perfmon pebs bts rep_good nopl xtopology nonstop_tsc cpuid aperfmperf pni pclmulqdq dtes64 monitor ds_cpl vmx smx est tm2 ssse3 sdbg fma cx16 xtpr pdcm pcid dca sse4_1 sse4_2 x2apic movbe popcnt tsc_deadline_timer aes xsave avx f16c rdrand lahf_lm abm 3dnowprefetch cpuid_fault epb cat_l3 cdp_l3 invpcid_single intel_ppin ssbd mba ibrs ibpb stibp ibrs_enhanced tpr_shadow vnmi flexpriority ept vpid fsgsbase tsc_adjust bmi1 hle avx2 smep bmi2 erms invpcid rtm cqm mpx rdt_a avx512f avx512dq rdseed adx smap clflushopt clwb intel_pt avx512cd avx512bw avx512vl xsaveopt xsavec xgetbv1 xsaves cqm_llc cqm_occup_llc cqm_mbm_total cqm_mbm_local dtherm ida arat pln pts hwp hwp_act_window hwp_epp hwp_pkg_req pku ospke avx512_vnni md_clear flush_l1d arch_capabilities



$ lspci  -v -s  $(lspci | grep ' VGA ' | cut -d" " -f 1)
2d:00.0 VGA compatible controller: NVIDIA Corporation TU104GL [Quadro RTX 4000] (rev a1) (prog-if 00 [VGA controller])
        Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company Device 12a0
        Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 203, NUMA node 0
        Memory at b9000000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=16M]
        Memory at 38ffe0000000 (64-bit, prefetchable) [size=256M]
        Memory at 38fff0000000 (64-bit, prefetchable) [size=32M]
        I/O ports at 8000 [size=128]
        [virtual] Expansion ROM at ba080000 [disabled] [size=512K]
        Capabilities: [60] Power Management version 3
        Capabilities: [68] MSI: Enable+ Count=1/1 Maskable- 64bit+
        Capabilities: [78] Express Legacy Endpoint, MSI 00
        Capabilities: [100] Virtual Channel
        Capabilities: [250] Latency Tolerance Reporting
        Capabilities: [258] L1 PM Substates
        Capabilities: [128] Power Budgeting <?>
        Capabilities: [420] Advanced Error Reporting
        Capabilities: [600] Vendor Specific Information: ID=0001 Rev=1 Len=024 <?>
        Capabilities: [900] #19
        Capabilities: [bb0] #15
        Kernel driver in use: nvidia
        Kernel modules: nouveau, nvidia_drm, nvidia



$ nvidia-smi
Mon Feb 24 12:26:30 2020       
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| NVIDIA-SMI 440.44       Driver Version: 440.44       CUDA Version: 10.2     |
|-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
| GPU  Name        Persistence-M| Bus-Id        Disp.A | Volatile Uncorr. ECC |
| Fan  Temp  Perf  Pwr:Usage/Cap|         Memory-Usage | GPU-Util  Compute M. |
|===============================+======================+======================|
|   0  Quadro RTX 4000     On   | 00000000:2D:00.0  On |                  N/A |
| 30%   36C    P8    11W / 125W |    619MiB /  7973MiB |      0%      Default |
+-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+



$ cat /proc/meminfo
MemTotal:       65639744 kB
MemFree:        50333684 kB
MemAvailable:   58616176 kB
Buffers:            2632 kB
Cached:          8924324 kB
SwapCached:            0 kB
Active:         10973608 kB
Inactive:        3013756 kB
Active(anon):    5005808 kB
Inactive(anon):   333068 kB
Active(file):    5967800 kB
Inactive(file):  2680688 kB
Unevictable:       10752 kB
Mlocked:           10752 kB
SwapTotal:       2097472 kB
SwapFree:        2097472 kB
Dirty:               620 kB
Writeback:            32 kB
AnonPages:       4999392 kB
Mapped:          1124604 kB
Shmem:            355216 kB
Slab:             550396 kB
SReclaimable:     295428 kB
SUnreclaim:       254968 kB
KernelStack:       33072 kB
PageTables:        79024 kB
NFS_Unstable:          0 kB
Bounce:                0 kB
WritebackTmp:          0 kB
CommitLimit:    34917344 kB
Committed_AS:   13232476 kB
VmallocTotal:   34359738367 kB
VmallocUsed:           0 kB
VmallocChunk:          0 kB
HardwareCorrupted:     0 kB
AnonHugePages:   1312768 kB
ShmemHugePages:        0 kB
ShmemPmdMapped:        0 kB
HugePages_Total:       0
HugePages_Free:        0
HugePages_Rsvd:        0
HugePages_Surp:        0
Hugepagesize:       2048 kB
DirectMap4k:     1891588 kB
DirectMap2M:    18767872 kB
DirectMap1G:    48234496 kB
```

**EDITS**

- I am building OpenCV 3.4.9

Comment: Just found out nvcc does not support -flto, so I guess WITH_CUDA and ENABLE_LTO are mutually exclusive in OpenCV (...?)